# Is there a physics explanation for why dry steering damages tyre?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction, everyday-life, rotational-kinematics

I used to think dry steering damages tyres because static friction takes place when the car is not moving, as opposed to dynamic friction when the car is moving. (Note: static friction has greater coefficient of friction than dynamic friction)

However, this can't be the explanation because, when a car is moving (i.e. rolling and not slipping), contact point of the tyres are stationary thus only static friction takes place at the contact point of the tyres. Therefore, whether the car is moving or not, only static friction takes place. Therefore, is there a valid physics explanation as to why dry steering damages tyres compared to steering while the car is moving?

Comment: When rolling at least the wear is spread out evenly  across the tire rather than concentrated in one spot.

Comment: So, turning the tires with the steering wheel against the static road involves no relative motion of tire and road surface?

Comment: @DJohnM Yes, it does, but when the car is not moving all stress is applied to one 'patch' of the tire. When the car is moving, the effective torsion angle for each spot on the tire is much smaller.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft:  My comment was intended to question the premise in the OP first sentence...